# conditional query running in relationship in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

here I have a code that I query inside a relationship that I want just 1 part to be executed if the user send the variable to me if not that query didn't run at all here is my code I commented in my code where I want my condition:

```
$bed_count = $request->get('bed_count');
$data = Accommodation::with(['city','accommodationRoomsLimited.roomPricingHistorySearch' =>function($query) use($from_date,$to_date){
$query->whereDate('from_date', '<=', $from_date);
                    $query->whereDate('to_date', '>=', $to_date);
         },'accommodationRoomsLimited' => function($q) use($bed_count){
          //here is I want my query to be executed if the user sends bed_count if not the code should skip this part
          $q->orWhere('bed_count',$bed_count);
        }])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not clear what are you trying to achieve.

1. If you want to eager load `accommodationRoomsLimited` all the time,
   But when user has provided bed count, you need to filter those `accommodationRoomsLimited` with this bed count.

**If that's so**

```php
$bed_count = $request->get('bed_count');

$data = Accommodation::with([
    'city',
    'accommodationRoomsLimited.roomPricingHistorySearch' => function($query) use($from_date,$to_date) {
        $query->whereDate('from_date', '<=', $from_date);
        $query->whereDate('to_date', '>=', $to_date);
    },
    'accommodationRoomsLimited' => function($q) use($bed_count) {
        if ($bed_count) {
            $q->where('bed_count',$bed_count);
        }
    }
]);
```

2. If you only want to eager load `accommodationRoomsLimited` only when user has provided bed count.

**Then**

```php
$bed_count = $request->get('bed_count');

$data = Accommodation::with([
    'city',
    'accommodationRoomsLimited.roomPricingHistorySearch' => function($query) use($from_date,$to_date) {
        $query->whereDate('from_date', '<=', $from_date);
        $query->whereDate('to_date', '>=', $to_date);
    },
])
->when($bed_count, function ($query, $bed_count) {
    $query->with([
        'accommodationRoomsLimited' => function($q) use($bed_count) {
            $q->where('bed_count',$bed_count);
        }
    ]);
});
```

Comment: thanks that saved me time !!! is when telling the query to load when the bedcount is given by user ??

Comment: Yes `when()` function first parameter is a condition, second parameter is what to do when condition passes.